# wordpress convert timestamp to date not correctly

Tags: date, timestamp

I use `wp_date()` function to convert and show dates with hours and minutes.

```
wp_date( 'Y/m/d - H:m:s',1598205923, 'Asia/Tehran' )
```

My problem is it shows `Y/m/d` correct. the hour is ok. but it shows `m:s` with a difference of about thirty minutes!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It works

`wp_date( 'Y/m/d - h:i:s', 1598205923, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Tehran') )`

Comment: Can you tell me why your code works? whats the deference?

Comment: Because you wrote `H:m:s` and `'Asia/Tehran'`. I changed to these `h:i:s` and `new DateTimeZone('Asia/Tehran')`

Comment: I know. I get it. I thought `m` means minutes. but it means month. Thankyou man.

Comment: I'm glad it helped